# Django Raise Error When Slug Already Exist

Tags: python, django, django-models, slug

I have a simple model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique=True, error_messages={'unique':"The slug of title has already been registered."})
```

I want to raise an error instead of creating a new slug whenever the slug already exist, but the error is not raised by the AutoSlugField

I tried another way by override the save method of my model like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    super(Competition, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and validate it in my serializer like this:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = MyModel
      fields = '__all__'
    
  def validate_title(self, val):
      if MyModel.objects.filter(slug=slugify(val)).exists():
          raise serializers.ValidationError('The slug of title has been registered.')
      return val
```

This actually works fine while creating a new object but has a problem when updating the object, since if the slug remains the same it raises the error, but it should not because I am updating the same object.

What is the most convenient way to do this? I really appreciate any help. Thank you...

Comment: Django's model don't run the validators. This is something the forms/serializers normally should do.

Comment: Yes, in the second method, I tried to do the validation through the serializer but this also raised the error while updating the object with the same slug. The only way I found is by creating new hyperlinkedmodelserializer for checking the id (verify it is the same object) then do the slug validation. But is there any convenient way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should exclude the object you are updating, so:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate_title(self, val):
        qs = MyModel.objects.filter(slug=slugify(val))
        if self.instance is not None:
            qs = qs.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)
        if qs.exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'The slug of title has been registered.'
            )
        return val
```

We thus check if there is an instance in the serializer to update, and if that is the case, we exclude from the queryset the object with the same primary key `.pk`.

Comment: Whoa, as a beginner I did not know about the exclude method before in DjangoQuerySet. Thanks for the answer it really helps me a lot! I need to read more on the Django documentation ^_^